# WebFlux Spring Boot Long Lived JSON Streaming REST End Point Pattern

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

This one is driving me nuts, I have a reusable need to build REST API's in Spring Boot React that follow the same pattern of exposing long lived streaming JSON API endpoints done today with ResponseEntity where I consume system events from a blocking queue using a component that is started and disposed within the life cycle of the API call. Every time a poll to the queue with a non-null response it sends the serialized object to the client can someone *please* explain howI would do this with WebFlux: - Create a WebFlux end point using annotations not a registry, that lets me send objects that are auto serialized or strings that I serialize through a streaming HTTP Connection.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/trade/v1/mock/dash/trades")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> brokerTrades() {
    StreamingResponseBody stream = out -> {
        int id = DRandom.getRandom(0, 5000);
        logger.debug("Starting brokerStream id " + id);
        final MockTradeEventList list = MockTradeEventList.newInstance(runtime.getExecutor(), 5);
        list.start();
        while (true) {
            try {
                DataGridUpdate update = list.nextUpdate(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                if (update != null) {
                    logger.debug("session " + id +  "payload " + update.toString());
                    out.write(DJson.serialize(update).getBytes());
                    out.flush();}
            } catch (Exception e) {
                list.dispose();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                logger.info("Exception/Closing session " + id + " "  + e.toString());
                return;
        }
        }
    };
    logger.info("steaming response {} ", stream);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON).body(stream);
}

}
```

``'

Something like this below i was able to run from guthub and it returned JSON objects serialized, the part I don't get is WebFlux.Create? Or Mono.create and then a publisher to create for sending or emitting objects and getting a handler method when client closes connection. thanks for any help, I've been trying to figure this out for longer than I would like to admit.

```
  // NOTE: application/stream+json is due to be deprecated in Spring 5.3 in favour of application/x-ndjson
    public Mono<ServerResponse> getQuoteJsonStream(final ServerRequest request) {
        return getQuoteStream(request, MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON);
    }
```

I also am running this behind a spring gateway server and want to verify I don't need any CORS config needed on this service behind the gateway.